# How to interpret docs on WinMain?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr, visual-studio-2022

Please look at the [WinMain docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain).

```cpp
int __clrcall WinMain(
  [in] HINSTANCE hInstance,
  [in] HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  [in] LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  [in] int       nShowCmd
);
```

How should I interpret this? Is `in` attribute optional which is denoted by the square brackets? If so, what does it look like.

I tried to compile a simple application in Visual Studio with the following flags:

```
/clr /permissive- /Zc:twoPhase-
```

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int __clrcall WinMain(
    [in] HINSTANCE hInstance,
    [in] HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    [in] LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    [in] int       nShowCmd
) {
    return 0;
}
```

But it won't compile and gives the following errors.

```
C2373 WinMain': redefinition; different type modifiers
C2337 'in': attribute not found
E0337 linkage specification is incompatible with previous "WinMain" (declared at line 1033) WinBase.h
E0147 declaration is incompatible with "int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)" (declared at WinBase.h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[in]` decorations are just for documentation. You can ignore them and just implement `WinMain` like in the sample [WinMain docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain):

If building for **Multibyte (a.k.a. ANSI)**:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, LPSTR cmdline, int cmdshow)
{
    return MessageBoxA(nullptr, "hello, world", "caption", 0);
}
```

If building for Unicode:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, LPWSTR cmdline, int cmdshow)
{
    return MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"hello, world", L"caption", 0);
}
```

Comment: What about `_In_` and `_In_opt` macros? Also, this example won't compile on my machine.  I had to prefix the strings with `L` to convert them to `wchar_t[]`.

Comment: ``_In_``, ``_In_opt``, etc. are SAL annotations. For more on these, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal). When not building for ``/analyze``, they are defined to be blank space.